Why don't touch god while wearing indigo clothes or neel clothes?
Rajendra das ji maharaj says do not touch god while wearing indigo textile clothes, do not wear narayan  blue clothes please answer my question with proof

Wearing clothes dyed with indigo or cultivating indigo are prohibited in scriptures but I don't think anywhere they mention the reason for which the prohibition exists.
See the following verses from Angiras Smriti's Chapter 1:


The three Varnas should perform the Chandrayana, if twice-born
persons, carelessly and out of error, eat indigo : for this is the
rule. (18)
The food, that is brought by a person putting on a cloth dyed with
indigo, stands the- giver in good stead, but] the partaker thereof
merely eats sin. (19)
Fasting for a day [is laid down! for Vipras fed with the rice which is
boiled by [a person putting on] a raiment dyed with indigo. (20)
The husband of the woman, who on tbe demise of her consort, puts on a
raiment dyed with indigo, goes to hell. The woman, too, [goes to hell]
thereafter. (21)
The corns, which one grows on a field sullied with the sowing of
indigo, are unworthy of being eaten by the twice-born. By eating
[them, one] should perform the Chdndrayana. (22)
Such a place (i.e., where indigo has been sown] should never be used
for a procession with idols, for the dedication of a bull, for
celebrating a sacrifice or for nicking gifts; for the earth [there]
has become contaminated. (23)
The ground, where indigo has been sown, remains impure for twelve
years and becomes pure thereafter. (24)

Going by these restrictions I think even the Indigo revolt that happened in Bengal in 1859 was triggered by such religious restrictions on the cultivation of indigo.
